# How to slide a form for create and edit in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to slide the `form` for `Create and Edit` in the same page of `index` without refreshing the page by using JavaScript without installing `gem`? is it any example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a **unique html node** in your page, for example,

```
<div id="main_content">
    #Any of your conntent will go here
</div>
```

And you links should have `remote=>true`.

Clicking on any link **will request the create or edit form** which will actually **replace the content of the `main_content`** div.

Here is reference that you can follow => **http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/**

You should find tons of resources on this in web. Let us know about any specific problem implementing the above.

**Some More Help:**

- [Ror Api Guide on link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)
- [Unrobustive Javascript Helper in Rails](http://solnic.eu/2009/09/08/unobtrusive-javascript-helpers-in-rails-3.html)
- [RailsCast on UJS](http://solnic.eu/2009/09/08/unobtrusive-javascript-helpers-in-rails-3.html)

**Update:**

Ok. If you are completely beginner then it might seem a bit tough. Then I would suggest to break the whole things up into smaller achievable steps. And achieve one by one. Eventually you will be successful.

Here are the steps that I would recommend:

1. Learning **Remote Link**

   - What is remote link
   - How to create these in rails 3.
   - Create a remote link yourself.
2. Learning **response handler**

   - What is response handler in a controller.
   - How to handle ajax response.
   - What is the corresponding view file of a ajax request
3. Writing ***.js.erb** file

   - Need to be familiar with javascript.
   - Need to know a basic of jquery.
   - Learn how to render a form in **js.erb** file
   - Set this form within a DIV of your main page.

I tried a make a simplest example of this. [**Find the codes here**](https://gist.github.com/3853453).

Share your problems of each step with us. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Samiron. Thanks. I will try to follow and implement this procedures and let you know. You are kind!.

Comment: Hi, its very hard to understand this for the beginners.

Comment: I ve made a simplest example demonstrating the remote links and responding. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. Its working fine. But the form built up with some javascript functions. So that's not working inside the form. One more question is is it possible to create a cancel button next to submit the form and make it close for new and edit?

Comment: You mean you want to show a `Cancel` button which will hide the `new` or `edit` form? If so, then you can use [**jquery hide function**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). There are lots of jquery effects are available which can be used to make your application more interactive.

Comment: Thanks samiron. I really appreciate your help. I sent a message to your facebook. Please reply me.

Comment: ok... but i didnt get any message yet... May be its routing through a super long way ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17716/discussion-between-vinay-and-samiron)

Comment: The link taught me very well to open the form in the same page. But the fields inside the form is not working. For example the drop downs are built with javascript. So, i guess something crashed. :(